# Serverless alb event does not have query params as a list with multiValueQueryStringParameters: true

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

So i have a serverless app where i am sending the request to an alb which gets redirected to a lambda function. My request is 
`/?filePath=a&filePath=b&filePath=c&filePath=d&pageSize=2` but in the event being passed to the lambda its shown as below:-

```
  {
  "requestContext": {
      "elb": {
          "targetGroupArn": "xyz"
       }
   },
   "httpMethod": "GET",
   "path": "/xyz",
   "queryStringParameters": {
      "filePath": "d",
      "page": "1",
   },
```

So, essentially instead of taking all the input files as a list in
`event.mutliValueStringQueryParameters: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, its taking only the last element as the queryParam.
My serverless alb event for this API is this:-

```
- alb:
  listenerArn: XXX
  priority: 2
  multiValueQueryStringParameters: true
  conditions:
    path: XXX
  method: GET
- http:
  path: XXX
  method: GET
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I wonder what you used to set up lambda as the targetGroup, when my alb request reaches lambda, there is no path and queryStringParams. I set it up using AWS console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself but I think you need to use a proxy integration to get the `multiValueQueryStringParameters` field.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/support-for-multi-value-parameters-in-amazon-api-gateway/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html

Note, when selecting an integration you can choose the payload version. If you select 2 there are no such proxy restrictions but instead of getting `multiValueQueryStringParameters` your values are concatenated together in a comma-delimited list.

`"filePath" : "a,b,c,d"`

Answer (score 0):

The correct property name is `multiValueHeaders` for alb in serverless to support multi value query parameters. But for some reason the serverless deploy doesn't update the relevant `Multi value headers` attribute in target group even if we added this property to serverless yaml. But we can manually update the attribute as in
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/lambda-functions.html#enable-multi-value-headers
After this though we start to get the multiValueQueryStringParameters in the event object but the usual field `queryStringParameters` is not available. Also it is mandatory that response object has to add additional `multipleValueHeaders` property as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/lambda-functions.html#multi-value-headers-response to make things works properly.